# How can I hidde a logo according the CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a web form with 2 logos and I need to show one of them according with the CSS file that will be using, for example if I user the css file named company1.css show up the logo1 and the same way for company 2

Any idea bout how can be done this ?

Thank your help

Answer (score 2):

I am now back at my computer so I have edited this post to a more appropriate format.
Use the logo as background for a div, give the div a fixed height and width.
In the CSS file add something like the following:

```
 .divclassname {
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
Background:url(someimage.jpg); 
Background-size: cover;
}
```

markup:

```
<div class="divclassname"></div>
```

Comment: Apologies for lack of formatting. I submitted the answer on my iPhone, and it did not go as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In your company1.css file:

```
.logo1 {display: block;}
.logo2 {display: none;}
```

In your company2.css file:

```
.logo1 {display: none;}
.logo2 {display: block;}
```

Comment: Hi I added the code but I'm seeing both logos, the html that I have is  <br>
 <div class="logo1">  <br>
<img src="~/images/wea_logo_rgb_2.png" />  <br>
</div>  <br>
<div class="logo2">  <br>
<img src="~/images/logo_premierhealth-01.png" />  <br>
</div>  <br>

Comment: Can you provide a link to your page or create a Fiddle? The rules could be overwritten by some other rules.

Comment: Hi Steffi, sorry what is s Fiddle?, I don't know how to write code

Comment: Never mind. Try @M_Griffiths code. To create a Fiddle, you just go to http://jsfiddle.net create your code, save it and paste the resulting link to your question or comment.

Comment: Hi, I just tested again and fix something in my code and worked fine, thank to both of you.